# Решаю задачу на питоне, никак не могу отсортировать список

Tags: python, сортировка, list

Вот задача:

Напишите функцию, которая создаёт комбинацию двух списков таким образом:

[1, 2, 3] (+) [11, 22, 33] -> [1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33]

Вот код:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [11, 22, 33]

c = a + b

def sorte(x):
    return x[0]

c.sort(key=sorte)

print(c)
```

Вилезает ошибка:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

PS: Не бросайте помидорки, я здесь только месяц :з

Comment: Через параметр `key` в функцию `sorte` передаются элементы списка `c` — числа. А в функции Вы пытаетесь индексировать их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sorte(x):
    return str(x)[0]
```

Comment: так в вопросе не сказано как ему нужно сортировать. Мне кажется, что имеется ввиду лексикографически

Comment: Простите, Вы правы. В вопросе действительно ничего не сказано о типе сортировки.

Comment: Стоит дополнить, что для передачи параметра `key` удобнее использовать анонимные функции. Кстати, можно напрямую сортировать строки, а не их первые буквы `c.sort(key = lambda x: str(x))`

Comment: **UPD**: ещё раз пересмотрел, для сортировки строковых отображений не нужна даже анонимная функция, можно передать `str` как ключ: `c.sort(key = str)`

Comment: Спасибо, это решило проблему

Comment: пожалуйста, но в следующий раз сформулируйте вопрос точнее) тогда и решение будет лучше)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не уточнили какой именно тип сортировки нужен. Предположу, что нужно что-то типо такого:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [11, 22, 33]
d = [111, 222, 333]

c = a + b + d

c.sort(key = lambda x: x / float(10 ** (len(str(x)) - 1)))

print(c)
```

Comment: Зачем такие сложности с нормализацией, если вы для этого всё равно приводите число к строке?

Comment: Мне просто показалось, что сортировка с числами 1.1 2.22 1 и т.д. более понятна. А вообще Вы правы, можно было просто использовать str(x). Но, как я уже сказал, так более наглядно.

Comment: Тогда уж логичнее не приводить к строке, а вычислить степень с помощью логарифма: `lambda a : a/10**math.floor(math.log(a, 10))`